# How to match template friend function in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a template class that declares a friend function which itself has template parameters. The code looks like this:

```
template <class T>
class C;

template <class T, class U>
void func(C<T>& t);

template <class T>
class C
{
    template <class U>
    friend void func<T, U>(C<T>& t);
private:
    template <class U>
    void f()
    {

    }
};

template <class T, class U>
void func(C<T>& t)
{
    t.f<U>();
}
```

But when I try to call `func`, I get a compilation error at the `friend` line:

> 'func': no matching overloaded function found

How can I make `func<T, U>` friend with `C<T>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key issue is that the friend you declared, is not the same as the previous declaration you provided. The first expects two template parameters, but the second (friend) you defined to accept only one. Once that is resolved, everything works:

```
template <class T>
class C;

template <class U, class T>
void func(C<T>& t);

template <class T>
class C
{
    template <class U, class TT>
    friend void func(C<TT>& t);
private:
    template <class U>
    void f()
    {

    }
};

template <class U, class T>
void func(C<T>& t)
{
    t.template f<U>();
}

int main() {
    C<int> c;
    func<bool>(c);
}
```

[Watch it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e551f90256adab2).

Note I switched `U` and `T` up, because I assumed you may want `T` deduced and `U` explicitly specified.

Comment: Looks like it works, but isn't it a problem that e.g. `C<char>::f` would be also visible in `func`? Can it be limited so that only `C<T>::f` is visible?

Comment: @IllidanS4 - I wouldn't bother really. A non-obvious feature of friend functions is that they aren't a template even if the befriending class is. So one has to declare a friend that is explicitly a template, and is a friend to all instantiations of `C`. The problem you note isn't really a problem, since the only object `func` will get is one that will match its second argument. And if you have control over it, just don't abuse that friendship with `C<char>`